# Creating sub-arrays of structs from within huge 2-dimensional struct array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I have a struct defined as

```
struct KVPair {
    char key[7];
    double value;
};
```

I create a 2-dimensional empty array of structs using

KVPair matrix[1000][500]={};

I populate the values later on.

However, what I want is that I should be able to create sub-arrays(2-dimensional) from within the huge 2-d  1000x500 array

Means, If reqired at some point in my program ,I should be able to create(or sub-allocate or whatever term one wants to use) something like

```
KVPair subMatrix[20][15];
```

and this should not use a new memory block but rather should use the existing blocks within the huge array. Sort of renting memory space.

and then again somewhere down the line

```
KVPair anotherSubMatrix[70][30];
```

and when the job is done, it should be vacating the rented memory space as well so that the next tenant can use it.

Doing this with a one-dimensional array looked somewhat straight-fwd after doing some google and stackoverflow search , but 2-d array looks challenging.

Any code suggestion is most welcome.

*Note: I need to do all this as allocating memory on heap is not allowed in my organization and also we strictly follow misra c guidelines where its mentioned 
that "Array declarations should include an explicit size specification"*

Answer (score 1):

Say, you're asked to get a sub matrix 'm', starting from row: 3, column: 4 and with dimensions of m[10][5];

```
KVPair matrix[1000][500] = { ... some values ...};

// first row index is '0', so row = 3 means 4th row
// and first column index is '0', so column = 4 means 5th column

int nRow = 10;
int nCol = 5;
int headRow = 3;
int headCol = 4;

KVPair *head = &matrix[headRow][headCol];
KVPair **m = malloc(nRow * nCol * sizeof(KVPair *));

for (int row = 0; row < nRow; row++) {
  for (int col = 0; col < nCol; col++) {
    *(m + nCol * row + col) = head + col;
    // printf("%s\n", (*m + nCol * row + col)->key);
    // getchar();
  }

  head += 500 - nCol;
}

free(m);
```

n.b. The new matrix 'm' will not contain **values** of the original matrix but **pointers** to the corresponding struct elements. Therefore, if you want to dereference & read the values of the struct of the matrix, you'll go like;

```
char *cTmp = (*m + nCol * row + col)->key;
double dTmp = (*m + nCol * row + col)->value;
```

p.s. Defining the struct as a typedef will make thing easier:

```
typedef struct {
    char key[7];
    double value;
} KVPair;
```